# SVG graphics won't appear in second floating relative div column using javascript and internal styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to create a system in Javascript that allows a user to click on an SVG embedded at 15% x and y size in a left div pane taking up half the page width, and make it appear 100% size in a pane on the right.

The right panel *is* there, because when I type into that div I see the letters come up. But for some reason the svg won't appear.

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("object").parent().attr("class") == "body") {
    $("object").attr("width", "15%");
    $("object").attr("height", "15%");
  } else {
    $("object").attr("width", "100%");
    $("object").attr("height", "100%");
  }
  $("#avatar_options object").click(function {
    var theObject = $(this);
    $("#avatar").html(theObject);
  });
});
```

```css
#avatar_options,
#avatar {
  width: 50%;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
#attr {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="avatar_options" class="body">
  <!-- heels -->
  <object id="svg/body_female_heels_african_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_heels_african_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="dark skin number 1"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_heels_asian_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_heels_asian_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="medium skin number 1"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_heels_blue_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_heels_blue_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="blue skin"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_heels_bright_red_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_heels_bright_red_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="bright red skin"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_heels_caucasian_light_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_heels_caucasian_light_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="light skin 1"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_heels_caucasian_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_heels_caucasian_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="light skin 2"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_heels_green_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_heels_green_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="green skin"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_heels_indian_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_heels_indian_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="skin regular red"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_heels_purple_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_heels_purple_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="skin purple"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_heels_tan_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_heels_tan_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="tan skin"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_heels_yellow_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_heels_yellow_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="yellow skin"></object>
  <!-- no heels -->
  <object id="svg/body_female_noheels_african_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_noheels_african_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="dark skin number 1"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_noheels_asian_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_noheels_asian_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="medium skin number 1"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_noheels_blue_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_noheels_blue_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="blue skin"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_noheels_bright_red_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_noheels_bright_red_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="bright red skin"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_noheels_caucasian_light_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_noheels_caucasian_light_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="light skin 1"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_noheels_caucasian_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_noheels_caucasian_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="light skin 2"></object>
  <!-- <object id="svg/body_female_noheels_green_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_noheels_green_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="green skin"></object> -->
  <object id="svg/body_female_noheels_indian_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_noheels_indian_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="skin regular red"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_noheels_purple_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_noheels_purple_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="skin purple"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_noheels_tan_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_noheels_tan_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="tan skin"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_female_noheels_yellow_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_female_noheels_yellow_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="yellow skin"></object>
  <!-- man body -->
  <object id="svg/body_male_african_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_male_african_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="dark skin number 1"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_male_asian_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_male_asian_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="medium skin number 1"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_male_blue_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_male_blue_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="blue skin"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_male_bright_red_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_male_bright_red_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="bright red skin"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_male_caucasian_light_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_male_caucasian_light_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="light skin 1"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_male_caucasian_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_male_caucasian_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="light skin 2"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_male_green_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_male_green_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="green skin"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_male_indian_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_male_indian_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="skin regular red"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_male_purple_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_male_purple_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="skin purple"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_male_tan_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_male_tan_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="tan skin"></object>
  <object id="svg/body_male_yellow_skin.svg" width="15%" height="15%" data="svg/body_male_yellow_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="yellow skin"></object>
</div>
<div id="avatar">
  <object id="svg/body_female_noheels_tan_skin.svg_2" width="100%" height="100%" data="svg/body_female_noheels_tan_skin.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="tan skin"></object>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#avatar_options").on('click', 'span', function() {
    $("#avatar").html($("#avatar span").add($(this)));
  });
  $("#avatar").on('click', 'span', function() {
    $("#avatar_options").html($("#avatar_options span").add($(this)));
  });
});
```

```css
#avatar_options,
#avatar {
  width: 50%;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

#attr {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#avatar_options span{
    width: 15%;
}

#avatar span {
    width: 100%;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
.pink {
  background: pink;
}
.orange {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="avatar_options" class="body">
  <span class="blue"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>
  <span class="pink"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>
  <span class="orange"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>
  <span class="red"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>
</div>
<div id="avatar"></div>
```

Can't really duplicate your code because I don't have the svg's, but I have attempted to simulate it using spans and font icons. Hope this helps.